# Suppress potential NullPointerException in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

This:

```
@Nullable
Item[] mItems;

public Item getItem(int position) {
    return mItems[position];
}
```

produces the warning:

```
Array access 'mItems[position]' may produce NullPointerException
```

I want to suppress this warning (I know that `getItem()` will not be called if `mItems` is null).

I've tried using the following annotations:

- `@SuppressWarnings({"NullableProblems"})`
- `@SuppressWarnings({"null"})`

as well as with the `//noinspection` notation, but they're all not working.

Using `@SuppressWarnings({"all"})` works, but it's obviously not what I'm looking for.

Android Studio doesn't offer any suppression option when I hit <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>, just the options to add a (useless) null check.

Comment: Please don't delete and re-post [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31931636/113632); use the "edit" button to add additional context to your question.

Comment: @dimo414 Previous posting was an accident (I pressed enter while adding tags and it posted it), the question was not ready. I tried editing it afterwards, but it wasn't possible.

Answer (score 73):

This works for me, but not sure why AS would want to use constant conditions as the suppressor. I think it has something to do with the skip null check as it's a constant condition (i.e., it'll always not be null).

```
@Nullable
Item[] mItems;

@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
public Item getItem(int position) {
    return mItems[position];
}
```

Comment: Don't know which is worse, adding a bunch of unnecessary asserts, or a SuppressWarnings with misleading terms.  Sigh.

Comment: Blame it on Google.

Answer (score 27):

If you want to prevent Android Studio from bothering you with those warnings while keeping them in the compiler simply go to Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Constant Conditions and Exceptions and uncheck it.

If instead you want to completely remove it then use the proper SuppressWarnings as suggested by the other answers :

```
@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
```

Answer (score 11):

@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions") does the trick for me.

Comment: then the next time I run inspections, I get "Redundant suppression", so I'm in an infinite loop

Comment: Brilliant answer, so much better than the one from 3 years earlier which suggests exactly the same, and in more detail.

Answer (score 6):

For me `@SuppressWarnings` did not work. I just add `assert` statement before the warnings to make it go away.

Your code should look like this:

```
@Nullable
Item[] mItems;

public Item getItem(int position) {
    assert mItems != null;
    return mItems[position];
}
```

I know you said that you are sure the `getItem()` will not be called if `mItems` is `null`. However, the inspector will not take into account that you already check before calling the function, hence the warning.

Or you can just leave it since `mItems = null` will never happen. But your code will look kind of messy, and for me it annoying.

Comment: This is an elegant solution.

Comment: You could add a clarification what assert does and when to use it. A quick quote from the doc: "An assertion is an assert statement containing a boolean expression. An assertion is either enabled or disabled. If the assertion is enabled, execution of the assertion causes evaluation of the boolean expression and an error is reported if the expression evaluates to false. If the assertion is disabled, execution of the assertion has no effect whatsoever. "

Comment: tests enjoy different coding standards from production code. If I dangle a reference, I WANT my tests to explode, WITHOUT excessive redundant assertions. How do I suppress this warning in the test files?

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate visually on Mac,

Go to `Preferences -> Editor -> Inspections`

Then in the search box type `constant conditions`

Then uncheck the one shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: This would disable it everywhere in the project though, which may be useful, but different from what's asked.

Comment: yes you are right i answered without fully reading the question..

Comment: This seems to have moved. As of IntelliJ 2022 3.3, I suppressed this warning by unchecking `Settings > Editor > Inspections > Java > Probable bugs > Nullability and data flow problems > Report problems that happen only on some code paths`